# How to sort elements of matrix?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I've tried to make it.
But I don't know the syntax to find the largest and smallest elements of a matrix. can help me?
The result is to make the matrix elements even row ascending and odd row descending

Comment: look at [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function

Comment: @Shai thanks but I have not succeeded. _A=input('input matrix: ');
[m,n]=size(A);
if mod(m,2)==1
    for i=1:2:m
    B1 = sort(A,2)
    end
    for i=2:2:m
    B2 = sort(A,2,'descend')
    end 
end
disp(B1)_

Comment: please refrain from posting code in comments - it is impossible to understand. If you have some code - edit your question to reflect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the even rows assorted in ascending order, and the odd rows assorted in descending order, then try the following

```
[m,n] = size(A);

for i=1:m
   if mod(i,2)~=0
       % row is odd
       A(i,:) = sort(A(i,:),'descend');
   else
       % row is even
       A(i,:) = sort(A(i,:),'ascend');
   end
end
```

The code iterates over each row and checks to see if that row is even or odd.  If odd, then we grab all elements in that row (`i` for the row number, `:` for all columns) and sort it in descending order and place that sorted row back in the matrix.  If even, then we do the same but sort in ascending order.  Type `help sort` for details on this function.

Comment: Okay but how to find maximum/minimum elements of matrix? because the result is element start from minimum element of matrix.

Comment: In the command window type `help max` and `help min` for details on the two functions that return the maximum and minimum value from a matrix.  For example, to get the minimum value(s) from `A` you would type `minValues = min(A(:));`.

Comment: input: [1 4 6 2 8;6 3 8 5 8;3 5 6 2 4;9 10 11 5 1], output:  
     [1     1     2     2     3;
     5     5     4     4     3;
     5     6     6     6     8;
    11    10     9     8     8;]

Comment: Some words around your above comment would be nice.  Are you saying that given the input matrix you want to sort all elements in ascending order and then re-arrange the rows such that odd rows are in ascending order and the even rows are in descending order (which differs from your original question)?  Look at `sort(A(:))` and observe what that returns, and then use `reshape` to get back the matrix you need.  Then use the above code to sort the rows in ascending or descending order given the row index.

Comment: i'm sorry :). I am a newcomer here. Do not understand how to post it.